# How to get the not applied jobs in the job table laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$joblist = JobDetail::join('candidates', 'job_details.id', '=', 'candidates.job_detail_id')
    ->where('candidates.user_id', Auth::id())
    ->where('candidates.job_detail_id', null)
    ->get();

SELECT job_details.* 
FROM job_details 
LEFT JOIN candidates 
ON job_details.id = candidates.job_detail_id 
WHERE candidates.job_detail_id IS NULL AND candidates.user_id = Auth::id()

This SQL query is not working.
I want to get the jobs that user didn't apply
```

[jobs and users mapping table - candidate table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPk6G.png)

[job details table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzgoC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

------------job details model---------------

```
public function candidates(){
     return $this->hasMany(candidate::class);
}
```

------------controller logic---------------

```
$userId = Auth::id();


$joblist = JobDetail:: whereDoesntHave('candidates', function ($query) use ($userId){ 
     $query->where('user_id', $userId); 
})->select('job_details.*')->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Consider fetching `jobList` from the candidate table :

```
$joblist = candidates::leftjoin('JobDetail','candidates.job_detail_id','job_details.id')
->where('candidates.user_id',Auth::id())
->whereNull('job_detail_id')
->select('job_details.*')->get();
```

Comment: Return an empty array.   
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1198 ▼
  #items: []
}